# Referenced project in another project restriction

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dll, visual-studio-2012

Is in Visual studio possibility to markup classes, so that there are accessible only is some projects ? 
I have domain project and this project is referenced into other projects (DLL on the build output). But I need that, the one project(Pr1)  use only part of logic in domain project and i don't want that rest od domain project logic will be accessibale in  Pr1. It is here some solution, except that brake it domain project into many small projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I need that, the one project(Pr1) use only part of logic in domain project and i don't want that rest od domain project logic will be accessibale in Pr1.

Then it sounds like basically you really, really should have separate projects.

You can grant one assembly *more* access than the norm, via [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) but you can't say "Everyone except assembly X can use this member."

(Even if you break the domain project up into two projects, you won't be able to prevent `Pr1` from having a reference to both projects... but at least that will be obvious.)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, i do some research about InternalsVisibleToAttribute but at least i know now the possibilities